# optimize way of following mysql query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id as c_id, w.id as w_id, c.city as cms_city,
               s.id as state_id, s.state_code as state
         FROM `cms_hotel` as c
         join webgeocities as w on c.city=w.name
                  and c.country_code=w.country_code
         join states as s on (w.state_code= s.state_code)
         group by c.id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die( mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $upd = "update cms_hotel set city_id  = '".$row['w_id'].
                  "' where id = '".$row['c_id']."'";
    $upd_result = mysqli_query($conn,$upd) or die( mysqli_error());

    $sel = "select id from city_matching where city='".$row['cms_city'].
                    "' and state_id='".$row['state_id']."'";
    $sel_result = mysqli_query($conn,$sel) or die( mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sel_result) == 0) {
        $ins = "insert into city_matching 
                 set city_name  = '".$row['cms_city'].
                  "' , state_id = '".$row['state_id']."'";
        $ins_result = mysqli_query($conn, $ins) or die( mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have millions of record in cms_hotel table so i want most optimize way to execute above queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove loop and `SELECT` expressions from code. Run next queries:

Update:

```
UPDATE `cms_hotel` as c 
JOIN webgeocities as w ON c.city = w.name 
  AND c.country_code = w.country_code
JOIN states AS s ON w.state_code = s.state_code
SET c.city_id = w.id, 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO city_matching (city_name, state_id)
SELECT c.city, s.id
FROM `cms_hotel` as c 
JOIN webgeocities as w ON c.city = w.name 
  AND c.country_code = w.country_code
JOIN states AS s ON w.state_code = s.state_code
LEFT JOIN city_matching AS cm ON cm.city=c.city
  AND cm.state_id=s.id
WHERE cm.city IS NULL
GROUP BY c.city, s.id
```

Comment: How I prevent duplicate data to insert in city_matching. Because  I need to run this every day to update record, And I want unique cities in city_matching table.

Comment: in insert: `LEFT JOIN city_matching AS cm ON cm.city=c.city
  AND cm.state_id=s.id WHERE cm.city is NULL GROUP BY c.city`

Comment: Edited `INSERT` in answer like @Mike says

Comment: @mnv `GROUP BY c.id` may duplicate cities !!! Use `group by c.city, s.id` OR `distinct` witchout 'gorup by'

Comment: @Mike, thanks. I removed `LEFT JOIN` and edited `GROUP BY` condition: `GROUP BY c.city, s.id`

Comment: @mnv NO. 'left join' need for suppress existing in "city_matching" rows. group by need for get unique cities in "not existing" set. Both parts needed.

Comment: For making the intent clear, change `SELECT ... GROUP BY..` to `SELECT DISTINCT ...`